# Create migration with uniqueness to a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, rails-console

I would like to create a migration that generates a model that looks like this:

```
# Table name: cities
# 
#  country_code :text
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  name         :string
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {:scope => :country_code, 
    message: "A name and country already exists for this entry" }

end
```

How can I create a [standalone migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) to create this model?

I am able to make the `:name` unique across the whole table:

```
rails g migration CreateCitites name:string:uniq country_code:text timezone:text
```

I'm having issues with creating the `:name` uniqueness relative to a `:country_code`.

---

Example:

> name: Sydney, country_code: Australia
>
> name: Sydney, country_code: Germany

Should be allowed

> name: Sydney, country_code: Australia
>
> name: Sydney, country_code: Australia

Should not be allowed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to enforce uniqueness across two columns in database is to create a unique index on those columns.

You can't create migration of this type from command line, but you can make changes in your migration file after it's generated.

```
def up
  create_table :cities do
    # etc.
  end

  # Add your index declaration here, after "create_table"
  add_index :cities, [:contry_code, :name], unique: true
end
```

Comment: **You can't create migration of this type from command line**